# React Router sending nested object as query

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am using `router.push` to update my url using the following code:

```
data = {url: 'abc', id: 1234}
this.props.router.push(
    path: 'app/p/1',
    query: {search: data}
)
```

However, this sets the query to: `?search=%5Bobject+Object%5D`.

I have even tried using jQuery param to convert nested objects to query but react router parses the query as a normal string

```
data = {url: 'abc', id: 1234};
search = $.param({search: data});
this.props.router.push(
    path: 'app/p/1',
    query: search
)
```

This results in the query being set to:

`0=s&1=e&10=i&11=t&12=e&13=_&14=u&15=r&16=l&17=%25&18=5&19=D&2=a&20=%3D&21=a&22=b&23=c&24=d&3=r&4=c&5=h&6=%25&7=5&8=B&9=s`

**EDIT**

The value of data is generated dynamically and is not fixed. It will always be a key: value pair.

**EDIT 2**

I would like to replicate the filter functionality used [here](http://demo.activeadmin.info/admin/users). 
All the filters are implemented inside the `q` object.
For example, a search for username would be `q[username]=abcd`

I would like to set the query as: `search[url]=abc&search[id]=123` 
which would mean: `search%5Burl%5D=abc&search%5Bid%5D=123` in terms of the URL.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I'll refer to `react-router` v3 docs to answer your question:

> I don't know what `react-router` version you're using, but it should be
>   the same to `v2` and `v4`

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/v3.0.5/docs

## The `router#push` method:

You can check that [`router#push`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3.0.5/docs/API.md#pushpathorloc) uses a `string` or a [`location descriptor`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3.0.5/docs/Glossary.md#locationdescriptor).

This `location descriptor`, when using an object, uses a [`Query`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3.0.5/docs/Glossary.md#query) object.

So, if you want to use the `location descriptor` object, your method should be like this:

```js
let data = { url: 'abc', id: 1234 };

this.props.router.push({
    path: 'app/p/1',
    query: data
});
```

### Using a string as query string:

If you want to pass a custom string (it may help you), you need to use `search`, that receives a [`QueryString`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3.0.5/docs/Glossary.md#querystring).

## Why you're having problems:

`react-router` expects the query object to be passed as key:value, I think it isn't able to handle the nesting cases.

## What you can do:

You can use the awesome [`qs`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs) module to handle that:

```js
const qs = require('qs');

let data = { url: 'abc', id: 1234 };
let query = qs.stringify({ search: data }); // produces: 'search%5Burl%5D=abc&search%5Bid%5D=1234'

this.props.router.push({
    path: 'app/p/1',
    search: query
});
```

Comment: In the first case I'm not using the jQuery param. However the first case doesn't use the params function

Comment: Ops, my bad, didn't see that. I'll update my question soon.

Comment: Even I will provide examples that I am trying to replicate. I will update the question

Comment: Updated my answer @AnirudhSridhar, check if it solves

Comment: Yeah it did. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let data = { url: 'abc', id: 1234 };

let query = [];

for (key in data) {
  query.push(`${key}=${data[key]}`);
}

search = query.join('&');

this.props.router.push(
    path: 'app/p/1',
    search: `?${search}`
)
```

Comment: The value of data is not fixed. I have added it in the question.

Comment: Yes, I knew. Just want to tell you to use `search` instead of `query`. Revised my code.